# Concurrent azure function with table storage

Tags: c#, azure, concurrency, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

Let's say I have azure function, which binds to azure service bus and makes some handling. For example, it iterates all available `_operationHandlers` and do some calculations

```
foreach (var operationHandler in _operationHandlers)
{
    await operationHandler 
            .HandleAsync(contractDto, cancellationToken);
}
```

each operationHandler is based on current state, which is stored in table storage. For example, `operationHandler` checks the state if it is not existed, create it.

```
var query = new TableQuery()
                    .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(
                        "PartitionKey",
                        QueryComparisons.Equal,
                        partitionKey));

return await dataSource.QueryAsync<T>(query, token);
```

The problem comes, when I receive two messages into azure service bus, then azure scale my function and proceed them concurrently, so each `operationHandler` will be in a race-condition state and persist the state, so at the end I will end up with two states persisted.

Hope it is clear, any suggestions how should I handle it?
Of course I can try to set `maxConcurrentRequests` in `host.json` to 1, but it doesn't seems to be a good approach.

UPDATED:
I didn't mention it initially the problem is not only in persisting the state twice, but also in some logic (if it is first creation it should output message to service bus, else another message should be sent), that should be skipped completely.

Comment: Instead of checking and then creating record in Azure Table, can't you simply try to insert the record and handle conflict error (HTTP Status Code 409)?

Comment: @GauravMantri sorry, I didn't mention it initially the problem is not only in persisting the state twice, but also in some logic (if it is first creation it should output message to service bus, else another message should be sent), that should be skipped completely.

Comment: It's still not clear to me... What kind of state are you persisting? What's your expected behavior when multiple functions are being run simultaneously?